# Using apply to parse through two data.frames [R]

Tags: r

I am looking for an easy way to vectorize an operation that takes the sequential value of a vector, and uses that as an index for a given column.  For example:

```
dataf <- replicate(10, sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))

> dataf
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   11   70   31   46   55    7   87   12   93    16
 [2,]   62   55   30   26   65   31    4   90   47    90
 [3,]   61   28   16   30   31   72   32    1   14    13
 [4,]   62   93    4   51   62   50    1   79   54    13
 [5,]   86   29   22   18   33   15   24    9   19    10
 [6,]   64   84   81   76   50   50   71   52   90    51
 [7,]    0   28   53   20   68   49   31   38   39    30
 [8,]   23   26   92   26   48   75   51    7   31     2
 [9,]   67   18   83  100   24   17    5   32   16    31
[10,]   51   23    4   81   77   85   57   67   90    74


ind <- c(1:10)
```

Using 'ind' as a column index for each row, what I want to do is perform an operation similar to this:

```
dataf[1, ind[1]]
dataf[2, ind[2]]
...
dataf[10, ind[10]]
```

And I am looking for the result to be a single vector:

```
> result
 [1] 11 55 16 51 33 50 31  7 16 74
```

I am hoping to avoid using a loop -- is there any way I can achieve this using a vectorized approach?

Thank you,
AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
dataf[cbind(1:10, ind)]
```

of course if you really just wanted the diagonal, you could do

```
diag(dataf)
```

but i'm assuming that your `ind` values aren't always sequential.